# Featured list in Android Google Play app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, google-play

I wonder how the main activity in the Android Google play app is implemented, is it a ListView, GridView or a TableLayout ?

what can be the best approaches to implement such a list ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check what is it exactly, you could use the Hierarchy View tool from ADT.

But my opinion is:

- As the amount of data there is constant and small, there is no need for a ListView
- As the number of "columns" per "row" varies, a GridView or a TableLayour are not a good fit either
- Because the layout is always the same, and only the content changes, the most obvious way would be to have a vertical LinearLayout as the root, and a GridView (or a horizontal LinearLayout) for every "row".

Comment: Thanks, I did as you said, it was a group of relative layouts aligned beside each other